# C# - DateTime / Integer Form Validation (where required field shouldn't be null / empty)

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, integer

I have an error popping up for the DateTime (DateofBirth) & int (TelephoneNumber) fields.

Currently doing a simple library application to register new customer records within the library - trying to implement validation so when Save button is clicked (new record is created), the fields are checked to see if data was submitted into them.

For eg. I used the below code for the NAME field, which worked correctly.

Further below are the DateofBirth & TelephoneNumber fields, which I implemented the code similar to Name, however, they don't work (I am getting errors). I am still new to C#, help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Example that works.

```
Name = this.txtName.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Customer's name is required. Please do not leave this field empty.");

            using (var erp_provider = new ErrorProvider())

                erp_Provider.SetError(this.txtName, "Customer's name is required. Kindly submit the details in the given field.");

            return;
        }
```

/////
Issues with the below code:

```
DateofBirth = DateTime.Parse(msktxtDateofBirth.Text);

        if (DateofBirth == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Customer's Date of Birth is required. Please do not leave this field empty.");

            using (var erp_provider = new ErrorProvider())

                erp_Provider.SetError(this.msktxtDateofBirth, "Customer's Date of Birth is required. Kindly submit the details in the given field.");

            return;
        }

TelephoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtTelephoneNumber.Text);

        if (TelephoneNumber == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Customer's Telephone Number is required. Please do not leave this field empty.");

            using (var erp_provider = new ErrorProvider())

                erp_Provider.SetError(this.txtTelephoneNumber, "Customer's Telephone Number is required. Kindly submit the details in the given field.");

            return;
        }
```

DateofBirth error:

(Exception Unhandled)
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

TelephoneNumber error:

(Exception Unhandled)
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Use the TryParse set of methods to look if the user input is valid for the datatype. For example Convert.ToInt32("") raises that exception. The same happens with DateTime.Parse and the string is not a valid date for your culture settings

Comment: Apologies, I'm still a noob in coding - Do you mean like this, please?

DateofBirth = DateTime.Parse(msktxtDateofBirth.Text);

Comment: Thank you @Steve, works well (as below)

bool isGoodDate = DateTime.TryParse(msktxtDateofBirth.Text, out DateofBirth);

if (DateofBirth == DateTime.MinValue)

Would the same be needed for the Integer (TelephoneNumber), please?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Notice that you don't need to check for DateTime.MinValue or null. TryParse will give you the boolean result required to drive your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with user input and validation of this input, you shouldn't use methods that raise an exception in case of invalid inputs. Instead the TryParse method's family allow you to *try* to convert the input and in case of error they don't raise an exception but return true or false.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParse(msktxtDateofBirth.Text, out DateTime DateofBirth))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Customer's Date of Birth is required. Please do not leave this field empty.");
    using (var erp_provider = new ErrorProvider())
        erp_Provider.SetError(this.msktxtDateofBirth, "Customer's Date of Birth is required. Kindly submit the details in the given field.");
    return;
}

if (!Int32.TryParse(txtTelephoneNumber.Text, out int TelephoneNumber))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Customer's Telephone Number is required. Please do not leave this field empty.");
    using (var erp_provider = new ErrorProvider())
        erp_Provider.SetError(this.txtTelephoneNumber, "Customer's Telephone Number is required. Kindly submit the details in the given field.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much @Steve, appreciate it a lot (had to fix the if's slightly on my end, now they work appropriately).